# F2084 Internal Error: AV06A334D3-W00000001-1 указывающая на строку implementation

Tags: delphi, ide, компилятор, delphi-xe3

Delphi XE3. При компиляции проекта получаю ошибку

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] JournalChangeUnit.pas(53): F2084 Internal Error: AV07AC34D3-WA101B2C0-1

которая указывает на строку с `implementation`. Для появления ошибки достаточно внести любое изменение в один конкретный юнит, кроме добавления/удаления пустых строк. После удаления изменений проект также не собирается. При работе с другими документами проблем не возникает.

Пробовал удалять сам файл(мало ли), dcu и пересобирать проект, не помогает.
Если внести изменения в документ а затем выйти/зайти в ide, то проект собирается.
Изменения в настройки, последнее время, не вносились.

Уточнение: Я понимаю что это магия, но данная ошибка проявляется только если вносить изменения в одну конкретную процедуру этого документа. Перед тем как перестает собираться отваливается intellisense - это первый признак что до перезапуска ide проект не пересоберется.

Comment: Проверь переносы строк в файле, не получился ли там микс из Виндовых и Линуксовых переносов (CRLF и просто LF). Все переносы должны быть однотипны, желательно CRLF.

Comment: Все строки с переносами CRLF. На всякий случаю изменил на LF и обратно не помогло.

Comment: Есть сильное подозрение что это просто баги IDE/Компилятора. Дельфи версий XE2-XE5, насколько я помню, славились именно такими "магическими" ошибками на ровном месте, независимо от кода. [Подробнее тут](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/F2084_Internal_Error_-_%25s%25d_(Delphi)).

Comment: Видимо это оно и есть(( Решил полностью переписать процедуру, до третей строки кода все было в порядке, а дальше та же беда. Проверил на другой машине, такая же проблема при изменении только этой процедуры

Comment: По моей ссылке есть решение от разработчиков: _In this case, a workaround is to set the Project > Options... > Delphi Compiler > Use MSBuild externally to compile to true._.

Comment: в 7-ке интернал на continue без for выдается.

Comment: Да, видел эту статью, но в Delphi Compiler не нашел ни чего удаленно похожего на этот параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка появлялась на XE3, когда объявил новый класс как

```
type    t = class
```

и не проходила до тех пор, пока не изменил на

```
type    t = class(TObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, в проекте слишком много циклических ссылок между модулями.

Модуль *A* ссылается на Модуль *B* из верхнего `uses`, а *B* ссылается на *A* из нижнего `uses`.  Такие связи могут проходить и через несколько модулей по цепочке. Чем длиннее цепочка, тем тяжелее компилятору. Старые компиляторы до *D7* лучше справлялись с этим, могли переваривать больше циклов. При переводе на новые компиляторы нужно рефакторить плохо структурированные проекты.

Для выявления зависимостей, удобно использовать утилиту *Dependency Analyzer* от *Model Mаker Tools*. Для развязывания зависимостей - использовать вынесение классов в абстрактный, интерфейсы, dependency Injection.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У меня похожая ошибка была, когда написал

```
type
  TMyType = double;
  TMyTypeHelper = record helper for TMyType
    function ToOtherType: TOtherType;
  end;

function TMyTypeHelper.ToOtherType: TOtherType;
begin
  Result := double(Self) * coeff;
end;
```

В принципе это работало, но в той ситуации, где возникла похожая ошибка (AV******-R00000000-1), удаление именно этого хелпера её исправило. Хелпер был в другом юните (не там, где происходила ошибка), и для ошибки обязательно было

1. Включить юнит с этим хелпером.
2. Включить ещё один юнит, где, в том числе, этот хелпер применялся (TMyType(a).ToOtherType)
3. В пострадавшем юните попробовать обратиться к полям структуры из второго юнита (SecondUnit.TSomeRecord.someField). Быстрее всего обнаруживалось, если указать неверное, отсутствующее поле. Структура сама не содержала TMyType, но содержала double.

Что именно из этого винегрета приводит к ошибке - не знаю, но подозреваю, что механизм разрешения имён как-то спотыкается на проверке хелперов, когда они для базовых типов и их употребления/объявления достаточно разбросаны по юнитам.